# How to most efficiently feed one ONNX model's output into another in java?

Tags: java, onnx, onnxruntime

I have two models built with ONNX, model A and model B. I use the [ONNX Runtime Java API](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/tree/master/java) to load these models and make inferences with them. The workflow is that I need to compute a prediction with model A and then feed the result from model A into model B:

```
x -> A(x) -> B(A(x)) -> y
```

When I call `resultFromA = A.run(inputs)`([OrtSession.run](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/java/src/main/java/ai/onnxruntime/OrtSession.java#L200)) the API returns a [Result](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/java/src/main/java/ai/onnxruntime/OrtSession.java#L1091).
Ideally I'd like to take that result and call `B.run(resultFromA)` but `run` only accepts `Map<String, OnnxTensor> inputs`. Do I really have to iterate over `resultFromA` and put its contents into a new `Map`? Or is their a method/usage from the API that I'm overlooking?

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
OrtEnvironment environment = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment();
OrtSession modelASession = environment.createSession(...);
OrtSession modelBSession = environment.createSession(...);

try (Result modelAResults = modelASession.run(inputTensor)) {
    
    try(Result modelBResults = modelBSession.run(modelAResults) { // <-------run won't take a Result object
        //do something with model B results...
    }
}
```

And what I have to do instead:

```
OrtEnvironment environment = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment();
OrtSession modelASession = environment.createSession(...);
OrtSession modelBSession = environment.createSession(...);

try (Result modelAResults = modelASession.run(inputTensor)) {

    Map<String, OnnxTensor> modelAMap = new HashMap<String, OnnxTensor>();
    modelAResults.forEach(e -> modelAMap.put(e.getKey(), (OnnxTensor) e.getValue()));
    
    try(Result modelBResults = modelBSession.run(modelAMap) {
        //do something with model B results...
    }
}
```

Comment: try casting the Result class to Map

Comment: Good idea but it doesn't work. Result implements AutoCloseable, Iterable<Map.Entry<String, OnnxValue>>. The cast results in java.lang.ClassCastException: ai.onnxruntime.OrtSession$Result cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: I checked the result class, they should've added a method that just returns a `map`.

Comment: :-( I agree. I'll submit a bug report there.

Comment: Reported to onnx runtime github as a "feature request": https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/6655

Comment: if know how to add that function to the code, create a pull request, and do it yourself its faster this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228586/discussion-between-waveshaper-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Collections.singletonMap like this:Collections.singletonMap(key, value) inside .run() to generate output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).